# How to get the count of the data returned by executing the TSI query?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I want to retrieve the data in TSI . I am sending the request from postman client like http://xxxxIPxxx/data-api/api/v1.0/data/variables
The request format is :

{
"date": {
"from": "2021-08-01T00:00:00Z",
"to": "2022-08-31T23:59:59Z"
},
"filter": ""  ,
"select": {
"properties": "value"
},
"limit": 100
}

I wan to get the count of the data returned after executing the script . Please help me how can I achieve that .

Comment: [Get Environments Availability API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/time-series-insights/dataaccessgen2/query/getavailability): Returns the distribution of event count over the event timestamp `$ts`.

Comment: Please refer [Query - Get Availability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/time-series-insights/dataaccessgen2/query/get-availability#code-try-0)

Answer (score 0):

> How to get the count of the data returned by executing the TSI query?

- ***Query - Get Availability***
  Returns the event count distribution and time range for the event timestamp ($ts).
- [Get Environments Availability API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/time-series-insights/dataaccessgen2/query/getavailability): Returns the event count distribution over the event timestamp '$ts'.
- It returns the count of events broken into intervals of time,

```cs
GET https://{environmentFqdn}/availability?api-version=2022-07-31
```

`environmentFqdn` can be obtained from the Azure portal

[image]
[image]
[image]